# Adding the elements of two struct arrays C

Tags: c

I am working on a problem where I have to accept two polynomials of arbitrary size and then add them together. I decided to use a struct hold the variables as such:

```
 typedef struct {
     int highPower;
     double polyMembers[];
 }poly;
```

I am using `malloc` to make the struct large enough to accept whatever amount of polynomial members are input.
My problem is with the adding function:

```
void addPoly(poly *a, poly *b)
{
   if(a->highPower == b->highPower)
   {
      double arr[a->highPower];
      for(int i = a->highPower;i>=0;i--)
      {
        arr[i] = a->polyMembers[i]+b->polyMembers[i];
      }
      printArr(arr,a->highPower);
   }
   else if(a->highPower>b->highPower)
   {
      double arr[a->highPower];
      for(int i = a->highPower;i>=b->highPower;i--)
      {
         arr[i] = a->polyMembers[i];
      }
      for(int i = b->highPower;i>=0;i--)
      {
         arr[i] = b->polyMembers[i]+a->polyMembers[i];
      }
      printArr(arr,a->highPower);
   }
   else
   {
      double arr[b->highPower];
      for(int i = b->highPower;i>=a->highPower;i--)
      {
         arr[i] = b->polyMembers[i];
      }
      for(int i = a->highPower;i>=0;i--)
      {
         arr[i] = b->polyMembers[i]+a->polyMembers[i];
      }
      printArr(arr,b->highPower);  
   }
}
```

For some reason this code works perfectly when the degree of the largest polynomial (I am using its position in the array `polyMembers` to denote a coefficients power) is odd, but when it is even the first two coefficients with the same highest power are not added instead the coefficient will be equal to the coefficient of polynomial `b`. Please help me figure out exactly what is going wrong as this is now wrecking my head. (`printArr` is just a simple for loop printing back out the added polynomials).
It was pointed out that the fault could be in how I accept the array in the first place, so I am adding the code I used for this:

```
poly *readPoly()
{
  double an;
  int n;
  double ax;
  int pos;
  printf("Enter first coefficient: ");
  scanf("%lf",&an);
  printf("Enter its power: ");
  scanf("%i",&n);
  poly *userInput;
  userInput = malloc(sizeof(*userInput)+ sizeof(double) * n);
  userInput->highPower = n;
  userInput->polyMembers[n] = an;

  for(int i=n;i>=0;i--)
{
  printf("Enter next coefficient: ");
  scanf("%lf",&ax);
  printf("Enter it's power: ");
  scanf("%i",&pos);

  if(pos == n){
  printf("You cannot enter 2 Values with the same power\n");
  //i++;
  printf("value of i: %d \n",i);
  }
  if(i+1==pos){
  printf("You cannot enter 2 Values with the same power\n");
  i++;
  printf("value of i: %d \n",i);
  }
  else if(pos>i+1||pos>n){
  printf ("You must enter the members of the polynomial in descending order.\n");
  i++;
  printf("value of i: %d \n",i);
  }
  else{
  userInput->polyMembers[pos] = ax;
  i = pos;
  printf("value of i: %d \n",i);
  }
}
  return userInput;
}
```

The line in the main I used was:

```
poly *SecondPoly= readPoly();
```

Comment: did you step through the code with your debugger?

Comment: @pm100 Currently in college and have not been taught how to use a debugger, was hoping there was a glaring error I had made.

Comment: sigh - you have to learn to use a debugger, that should be the second thing you learn after learning how to edit and compile 'hello world'

Comment: @pm100 We have never used one for C, what i did instead of debug like that was add print statements everywhere to see the status of variables and still couldn't see where the problem was.

Comment: what tools / platform / edit / compiler are you using?

Comment: you're indexing out of bounds.  `double arr[a->highPower]` declares an array with `a->highPower` elements 0 to `a->highPower - 1`.  When you index  `arr[i]` when `int i = a->highPower` in your loop, you are going out of bounds.

Comment: @pm100 We use emacs and compile in the terminal

Comment: if you use gcc to compile then google for a tutorial on gdb, its real easy to use. If not gcc then ask around (TA, second year students,..) for what debugger you should use and learn that. It will take an hour and its well worth the investment

Comment: @pm100 ya it is gcc thanks for the tip will do

Comment: How is your 'add polynomial' function going to return the result?  Printing a polynomial is fine (especially as a debugging tool), but surely you need to store the result somewhere?  You ought to be able to combine the three cases into one set of loops.  I'd expect to see a loop to add the common sections into the result, then a loop to add what's left from the first into the result, then a loop to add what's left from the second into the results — and at most one of the last two loops would do anything.  The space to be allocated is the larger of `a->highPower` and `b->highPower`.

Comment: Also, I agree that you're definitely not allocating enough space in the local arrays in the addition code, but you've not shown how you initialize arrays, and there could be trouble there, too.  The odd/even dichotomy could be because when you `malloc` space, the size requested gets rounded up to a larger number, and for the one that works, this extra space protects you (accidentally, and it isn't something to be relied on), but the other doesn't get any extra space and so writing out of bounds does serious damage to some memory that matters.

Comment: Please read about how to create an MCVE — [MCVE].  Having an MCVE would tell us whether there are problems in the code not shown above that affect the code shown.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The reason I don't really need to store it is because its a college assignment where no real marks are going for storing, only outputting the right result and I thought it would be easier to output than store. That obviously turned out to be untrue but now I'm being stubborn. I also added the missing code as suggested.